# Extract multiple numeric values from string with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column with data in a special “format”. Example:

```
L100000
L50
L5
S10
S15L10
S20
S90
S10
S10L5
S10L40
S10L5
```

The value consists of an “S” and/or an “L”, each with a number following the letter.
I need to write a query, which will return two columns, “S” and “L”, which will have only the coresponding numeric value following the letter.
The above example should look like this:

```
S         L  
========  ==========
0         100000
0         50
0         5
10        0
15        10
20        0
90        0
10        0
10        5
10        40
10        5
```

If no "S" or "L" is found, the default value is zero.

Comment: Is there some reason why these aren't inserted in separate columns in the first place?  It would be much easier to create a computed column that puts them back together than write a function that parses and extracts the values.

Comment: I'm importing data from a ... let's call it "interesting" ... legacy database, where the developer chose to store multiple values in a single nvarchar column. I'm trying to clean it up, and split the data into separate columns in an import routine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (RowValue varchar(30))

INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('L100000')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('L50')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('L5')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('S10')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('S15L10')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('S20')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('S90')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('S10')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('S10L5')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('S10L40')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('S10L5')

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN LocationS>0 AND LocationL=0 THEN RIGHT(RowValue,Length-1)
        WHEN LocationS>0 THEN SUBSTRING(RowValue,2,LocationL-2)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS S
    ,CASE
         WHEN LocationS=0 AND LocationL>0 THEN RIGHT(RowValue,Length-1)
         WHEN LocationS>0 AND LocationL>0 THEN RIGHT(RowValue,Length-LocationL)
         ELSE NULL
     END AS L
    ,RowValue
    FROM (SELECT
              RowValue
                  ,CHARINDEX('S',RowValue) AS LocationS
                  ,CHARINDEX('L',RowValue) AS LocationL
                  ,LEN(RowValue) AS Length
              FROM @YourTable
         ) dt
```

OUTPUT

```
S                              L                              RowValue
------------------------------ ------------------------------ --------------
NULL                           100000                         L100000
NULL                           50                             L50
NULL                           5                              L5
10                             NULL                           S10
15                             10                             S15L10
20                             NULL                           S20
90                             NULL                           S90
10                             NULL                           S10
10                             5                              S10L5
10                             40                             S10L40
10                             5                              S10L5

(11 row(s) affected)
```

if you have loads of data give this a try, it may be faster (has same output, basically removed the derived table and made everything use inline functions):

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('S',RowValue)>0 AND CHARINDEX('L',RowValue)=0 THEN RIGHT(RowValue,LEN(RowValue)-1)
        WHEN CHARINDEX('S',RowValue)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(RowValue,2,CHARINDEX('L',RowValue)-2)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS S
    ,CASE
         WHEN CHARINDEX('S',RowValue)=0 AND CHARINDEX('L',RowValue)>0 THEN RIGHT(RowValue,LEN(RowValue)-1)
         WHEN CHARINDEX('S',RowValue)>0 AND CHARINDEX('L',RowValue)>0 THEN RIGHT(RowValue,LEN(RowValue)-CHARINDEX('L',RowValue))
         ELSE NULL
     END AS L
    ,RowValue
    FROM @YourTable
```

Comment: I just saw the last line of the question `f no "S" or "L" is found, the default value is zero.` to achieve that, just change the two CASE statement's ELSE clause from `ELSE NULL` to `ELSE 0`.  Also the sample data from the question didn't contain a NULL row or a row with a junk value like 'ABC', my queries will return the CASE default for both.

Comment: Excellent, your second suggestion worked "right out of the box". Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
SVal = CASE 
  WHEN PATINDEX('S%L%', TextVal) > 0 THEN REPLACE(LEFT(TextVal, CHARINDEX('L', TextVal) - 1), 'S', '')
  WHEN PATINDEX('S%', TextVal) > 0 THEN REPLACE(TextVal, 'S', '')
  ELSE '0'
END,
LVal = CASE
  WHEN PATINDEX('S%L%', TextVal) > 0 THEN REPLACE(RIGHT(TextVal, LEN(TextVal) - CHARINDEX('L', TextVal)), 'L', '')
  WHEN PATINDEX('L%', TextVal) > 0 THEN REPLACE(TextVal, 'L', '')
  ELSE '0'
END
FROM StringList
```

Assumes S always comes before L. Also you might want to cast the results as numbers (they are strings now) depending on what you need for the output.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a clr-based function which would use a regex to extract the S or L value from the string. You could use it like this:

```
insert new_table (s_value, l_value)
  select getValue('S', original_value), getValue('L', original_value)
    from original_table
```

Answer (score 0):

not tested but should be close assuming s always appears before l:

```
select
    case when charindex(data, 's') <> 0 then
        substr(data, charindex(data, 's'), charindex(data ,'l'))
    else 0 end
    , case when charindex(data, 'l') <> 0 then
        substr(data, charindex(data, 'l'))
    else 0 end
from some_table
```

Comment: `Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3 'substr' is not a recognized built-in function name.` and you get: `Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 The substring function requires 3 argument(s).` after that.